# Split DATEDIFF into separate months

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I currently have an issue whereby I am doing DATEDIFF in minutes between a start date and end date, however I when this date goes over into a new month I need the figures to be separate for each month.

Please see example data (both Text and Image view);

```
SELECT [BookingNum]
  ,[StartDate]
  ,[EndDate]
  ,[Location]
  ,DATEPART(m,startdate) AS [Month]
  ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,StartDate,EndDate) AS [Minutes]
FROM [Test].[dbo].[Booking]


BookingNum  StartDate                  EndDate        Location Month Minutes
   1    2019-02-05 12:54:00.000 2019-02-08 15:00:00.000 Area 1  2   4446
   2    2019-05-02 10:41:00.000 2019-05-10 12:39:00.000 Area 2  5   11638
   3    2019-06-01 10:30:00.000 2019-06-04 09:25:00.000 Area 3  6   4255
   4    2019-02-02 09:41:00.000 2019-04-20 11:54:00.000 Area 1  2   111013
   5    2019-03-29 19:09:00.000 2019-04-02 10:41:00.000 Area 3  3   5252
```

For rows 4 & 5 there would need to be additional rows as they go across multiple months.

Example for the data in row 4, I would want to see;

```
StartDate                  EndDate            Location Month Minutes
2019-02-02 09:41:00.000 2019-02-28 23:59:00.000 Area 1  2   38298
2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 2019-03-31 23:59:00.000 Area 1  3   44639
2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 2019-04-20 23:59:00.000 Area 1  4   28074
```

This would then give me the total minutes for that month only between the start and end date.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Tag the question with the database you are using.  Your current code is also helpful.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, etc). Also, it's best not to link to images, plain text is good.

Comment: Thanks, ive added SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using recursive CTE as follows. This calculates multiple months between startdate and enddate.
Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/26568/4

```
create table #temp(
BookingNum int,
StartDate datetime,
EndDate datetime,
Location varchar(25),
)

insert into #temp
values(1,'2019-02-05 12:54:00','2019-02-08 15:00:00','Area 1'),
(2,'2019-05-02 10:41:00','2019-05-10 12:39:00','Area 2'),
(3,'2019-06-01 10:30:00','2019-06-04 09:25:00','Area 3'),
(4,'2019-02-02 09:41:00','2019-05-20 11:54:00','Area 1'),
(5,'2019-03-29 19:09:00','2019-04-02 10:41:00','Area 3')


;WITH cte AS
  (
    SELECT BookingNum,
         StartDate,
         CASE
            WHEN DATEPART(m, EndDate) > DATEPART(m, startdate)
            THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, startdate) + 1, 0))
            ELSE EndDate
         END AS EndDate,
         Location,
         DATEPART(m, EndDate) - DATEPART(m, startdate) AS MonthDiff
    FROM #temp

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.BookingNum,
         CASE
            WHEN cte.MonthDiff > 0
            THEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(month, 1, cte.StartDate)), 0)
            ELSE cte.StartDate
         END AS startDate,
         CASE
            WHEN cte.MonthDiff > 0  AND DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DATEADD(month, 1, cte.StartDate)) + 1, 0)) < t.EndDate
            THEN DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DATEADD(month, 1, cte.StartDate)) + 1, 0))
            ELSE t.EndDate
         END AS EndDate,
         cte.Location,
         (cte.MonthDiff - 1) MonthDiff
    FROM cte
        INNER JOIN #temp t ON cte.BookingNum = t.BookingNum
    WHERE cte.MonthDiff > 0
)
SELECT BookingNum,
      StartDate,
       EndDate,
       Location,
       DATEPART(m, startdate) AS month,
       DATEDIFF(minute, startdate, enddate) AS minutes  
FROM cte
ORDER BY 1;



drop table #temp
```

Result:

```
BookingNum  StartDate               EndDate                 Location                  month       minutes
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------- ----------- -----------
1           2019-02-05 12:54:00.000 2019-02-08 15:00:00.000 Area 1                    2           4446
2           2019-05-02 10:41:00.000 2019-05-10 12:39:00.000 Area 2                    5           11638
3           2019-06-01 10:30:00.000 2019-06-04 09:25:00.000 Area 3                    6           4255
4           2019-02-02 09:41:00.000 2019-02-28 23:59:59.000 Area 1                    2           38298
4           2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 2019-03-31 00:00:00.000 Area 1                    3           43200
4           2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 2019-04-30 00:00:00.000 Area 1                    4           41760
4           2019-05-01 00:00:00.000 2019-05-20 11:54:00.000 Area 1                    5           28074
5           2019-03-29 19:09:00.000 2019-03-31 23:59:59.000 Area 3                    3           3170
5           2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 2019-04-02 10:41:00.000 Area 3                    4           2081
```

Comment: How do I change this to calculate the end date month, at present it is only calculating the whole end date month rather than upto when the end date actually is?

Comment: I would tend to avoid recursive ctes as they don't scale particularly well performance wise.

Comment: i have updated the code. it should now take the proper end date

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Recursive CTE should do the trick! Basically, use recursion to keep getting the start date through the lesser of the EOM and the end date, until ultimately you reach the end date.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2770e/4)

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (bookingnum INT, sd DATETIME, ed DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
(1, '2/5/2019 12:54 PM', '2/8/2019 3:00 PM'),
(2, '5/2/2019 10:41 AM', '5/10/2019 12:39 PM'),
(3, '6/1/2019 10:30 AM', '6/4/2019 9:25 AM'),
(4, '2/2/2019 9:41 AM', '5/20/2019 11:54 AM'),
(5, '3/29/2019 7:09 PM', '4/2/2019 10:41 AM')

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT bookingnum, sd, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(sd)) eom, ed,
        CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(sd)) < ed THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(sd)) else ed END AS applied_ed
    FROM @tbl
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT bookingnum, applied_ed, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(applied_ed)) eom, ed,
        CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(applied_ed)) < ed THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(applied_ed)) else ed END AS applied_ed
    FROM cte
    WHERE applied_ed < ed
)
SELECT bookingnum, sd, applied_ed AS ed, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, sd, applied_ed) minutes
FROM cte
ORDER BY bookingnum, sd
```

Returns:

```
bookingnum  sd                      ed                          minutes
1           2019-02-05 12:54:00.000 2019-02-08 15:00:00.000     4446
2           2019-05-02 10:41:00.000 2019-05-10 12:39:00.000     11638
3           2019-06-01 10:30:00.000 2019-06-04 09:25:00.000     4255
4           2019-02-02 09:41:00.000 2019-03-01 00:00:00.000     38299
4           2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 2019-04-01 00:00:00.000     44640
4           2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 2019-05-01 00:00:00.000     43200
4           2019-05-01 00:00:00.000 2019-05-20 11:54:00.000     28074
5           2019-03-29 19:09:00.000 2019-04-01 00:00:00.000     3171
5           2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 2019-04-02 10:41:00.000     2081
```

Comment: Just used this on not example data where this can span a large number of months however where this is spanning over 3 separate months this will only calculate the startdate month and the enddate month. How could I alter this to capture any months in the middle aswell?

Comment: If you have a look at the solution below, that will expand the full result set out.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you will need to create an additional table to join to that contains the months.  You would then join to that table where the month of the date is between the dates in the calendar table, to do this you need to use a dateadd/datediff function to round your date to the first of the month e.g.: `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, StartDate),0)`. This works by calculating the difference in months between some random start date (in this case 0, I.e. 1/1/1900) and then adding those months back on to the start date.

Then you will need to round your start or end date up or down to the end of the month if they are not in the same month as the calendar table record, which will allow you to do a new calculation for the time.

The whole code would look something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #MonthDate
(MonthDate date PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO #MonthDate (MonthDate)
VALUES ('20190101'),('20190201'),('20190301'),('20190401'),('20190501'),('20190601');

WITH RoundedDates As 
(SELECT b.StartDate,
B.EndDate,
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, b.StartDate),0)  AS RoundedStartDate,
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, b.EndDate),0)  AS RoundedEndDate
FROM Test.dbo.Booking AS b)
SELECT rd.StartDate
, rd.EndDate
, DATEDIFF(minute, CASE WHEN rd.RoundedStartDate = md.MonthDate THEN rd.StartDate ELSE md.MonthDate END, CASE WHEN rd.RoundedEndDate = md.MonthDate THEN rd.EndDate ELSE DATEADD(month,1,md.MonthDate) END) AS Minutes
FROM RoundedDates AS rd
INNER JOIN #MonthDate as md
   ON md.MonthDate BETWEEN rd.RoundedStartDate AND rd.RoundedEndDate
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/70730/2